# How to calculate social share count efficiently using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, social-media

I am working on classified ads web application using asp.net Mvc-3 C#.

Every ad can share on social media like facebook,twitter,google plus ,linkedin.

I am calculating how many times ad is share on these website and saving this record in database.

Using this function

```
 string jsonString = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(URL-of-ad);
 var serialize= new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
 var dictionary = serialize.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString);
 var twitter = dict["count"];
 var facebook= dict["share_count"];

// calculating for other website by this function
```

This is function is working fine but very time consuming for every ad .I have thousand of ads so i have to loop through thousand time and call this function for every ad.

I am calling this function twice in a day.

There is any other better and fast way to do this task?

Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think of improving your design

1 - Create a Windows Service and set it to run twice a day , most probably figure out when the  traffic on your site is very minimal.

2- Move the Sharing count logic into windows service which will do it in another process and free up your main application.

3- Downloading something which is dependent upon the network speed so make yopur downloading Asynchronous rather than synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

1. Run this in parallel, such as using [`Parrallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx), passing in the URL of the add, or an async version, such as [DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync.aspx). Both will run multiple downloads at the same time.
2. Run this when the page is loaded that shows the add. Load the add then do a web service call to the server to get the `count` and `share_count`. It may be a bit more work but it will be more up to date and, if each add is shown rarely, this may be more efficient.

I assume you are not running this during page creation but, if you are, move it to a separate service or process as Saurabh suggests.